# Grafana - Modify Alert Message

Tags: monitoring, grafana, slack, templating

I am using Grafana version **v8.3.3** and have set up Slack alerts but the alerts are formatted in a certain way and I don't see an option to change it.

There is a section **Add details for your alert** which is great but the alert contains all these fields and I can't find where to control which one to display in Slack message and which ones to hide. I just want to send a message with value and a brief description without annotations, labels, source, and silence.

```
**Firing**
Value: [ metric='disk_used_percent' labels={InstanceId=i-..., path=/} value=28.528058875324813 ]
Labels:
- alertname = CI Jenkins instance FREE space alert
- notification = slack
Annotations:
- summary = CI Jenkins instance is running out of space. Please investigate.
Source: http.....
Silence: http....
```

Answer (score 1):

By providing custom message in contact point, I could able to avoid source, silence, query etc., being sent as part of alert notification message.